# NUnit игнорирует тесты, не запускаем мои тесты

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, nunit

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyProjectForTestNUnit
{
[TestFixture]
public class NUnitTesting
{
    [Test]
    public void IsNotNull()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(1);
    }
}
}
```

Создал новый проект установил NUnit 3.12.0,NUnit3TestAdapter.
Метод IsNotNull() попросту не запускаеться.
[image: после запуска]

Comment: Так-то да, нужен NUnit3TestAdapter. Попробуйте выгрузить-загрузить проект. Или вообще перезапустить Студию.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Проект был чистый из за этого не хватало либ, для того что бы тесты запускались нужно иметь `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.9.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.9.0" />`

Comment: У вас .NET Core? Это нужно явно указывать в вопросе.